# Best practice for using v-model with Vue Apollo? - "Cannot assign to read only property"

Tags: vuejs3, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I am new to graphQl and apollo, and trying to wrap my head around the design pattern for updating and retrieving data?

As an example, lets say I get a list of users like so:

```
  const USER_QUERY = gql`
    query users {
      app_user {
        id
        first_name
        last_name
        email
      }
    }`
    
    const { result: users, loading: loading_users, error: error_users } = useQuery(USER_QUERY);
```

In my component, I'd like to allow the user to edit their first name. My thought was that I would bind the first_name property via v-model, and then when they click save, the update mutation is performed:

```
 <input v-model="users.app_user[0].first_name" />
 <button @click="updateUser">Update User</button>
```

However, this gives the error:

```
Cannot assign to read only property
```

What is the 'standard' design pattern for 1) Fetching a record via query, 2) allowing the user to edit one or more fields on that record, and 3) Performing the mutation to commit those changes to the database.

Comment: Did you figure this out? It would seem to be the best practice, but I'm getting a similar error.